# Replacing current quote with a stored Quote

Tags: cart, quote, persistent

Background:

There is a store with two sites and shopping cart has to be shared among the two. To facilitate this, I set a field in session and store the quote-id in it. When we switch store, the quote is loaded from database.

Problem: Currently the quoteid is being passed successfully but we're unable to replace the quote. I tried `quote->merge` and `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuote / setQuoteId`, but with no success. I can see the correct quote number being passed among sites.

Every constructive suggestion is welcomed.